# Accessing dom elements exercise

Tags: javascript, dom

I need your help on accessing dom elements.
Basically i have a slider with bullets and i want to log the text content of the selected slide every time i click on a bullet.

under my ul i have two elements:
a div that contains another div having a class of "flickity-slider" and an ol

I initially started with this script but realized that it would turn all the dots to class "is-selected"

```js
var dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dots');
var slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(dots, edot=>{
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(slide, eslide=>{
    if (edot.className = 'dot is-selected') {
      if (eslide.className = 'slide is-selected') {
        console.log(eslide.textContent);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="slider text-center" data-paging="true" data-children="3">
  <ul class="slides flickity-enabled is-draggable" tabindex="0">
    <div class="flickity-viewport" style="height: 362.797px;">
      <div class="flickity-slider" style="left: 0px; transform: translate3d(-296.79%, 0px, 0px);">
        <li class="slide is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 300%;"> <img alt="Image" src="img/cowork-8.jpg">
        <h5>Gotham Rounded Light</h5>
        <p> Gotham Rounded is a technical letter that<br>goes from scale. </p>
        </li>
        <li class="slide" style="position: absolute; left: 100%;"> <img alt="Image" src="img/cowork-10.jpg">
        <h5>Highlighting data<br></h5>
        <p> We were required to use a lot of graphics. This was extremely challenging, for it is no easy tasks. </p>
        </li>
        <li class="slide" style="position: absolute; left: 200%;"> <img alt="Image" src="img/cowork-11.jpg">
        <h5>Initial Design</h5>
        <p><b>For</b> <b>our</b> <b>first</b> <b>design,</b> we chose a light-colored background to bring out the shadows of the graphics and illustrations.</p>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ol class="flickity-page-dots">
      <li class="dot is-selected"></li>
      <li class="dot"></li>
      <li class="dot"></li>
    </ol>
  </ul>
</div>
```

help would be appreciated. Hope i was clear

saw a previous comment about the queryselector - I just updated it

Comment: Check your code: dots only contains one element and is not an array because `document.querySelector` selects the first element that it found. Your var slide is an array! For each doesnt work like this. You can use foreach for example for slide like this: `slide.forEach((item, index, array) => {/*...*/})`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this where you log the relevant slide based on the index of the dots:

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide')
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot')

Array.from(dots).forEach((dot, index) => {
   dot.onclick = () => {
    console.log(slides[index].textContent)
  }
 })
```

So if you click on dot/bullet number 1, you would log the content of slide number 1.